# Scope issue when passing property of object into method. (opencv related)

Tags: c++, opencv, properties, scope

Just learning C++, encountered an issue that i'm not really sure why the following is the case.

Doesn't work

```
ChildObject in = myObject.getObjFromVector(0);
ChildObject out = myObject.getObjFromVector(1);
doSomething(in.property, out.property); // void doSomething(Thing &in, Thing &out)

where 
ChildObject& getObjFromVector(int index)
```

Works

```
process(myObject.getObjFromVector(0).property, myObject.getObjFromVector(1).property);
```

In case your wondering, though i don't think its relevant, Thing is Mat from opencv. This question however is about why the above works in one way but not the other.

Interestingly [Which is more performant, passing a method the entire object, or a property of that object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060050/which-is-more-performant-passing-a-method-the-entire-object-or-a-property-of-t) suggests that both should work, or at least be acceptable. I'm definately doing something wrong though and this might be down to something in openCV i'm not aware off.

edit:
I'm effectively carrying out some image manipulation on the .property value. like

```
process (Mat &src, Mat &out){
...
pyrDown(src, result, Size(src.cols / 2, src.rows / 2));
...
```

WHen its not working, i'm not seeing the pyrDown take effect.

Comment: Does `getObjFromVector()` return a reference? If so, the problem may be object slicing (though I am not sure what _doesn't work_ means).

Comment: ChildObject& getObjFromVector(int index) though what i don't understand is why the same method  is used in the working example.

Comment: What types are the `Thing`s expected by doSomething?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly due to [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) (I am not familiar with openCV). In the first example:

```
ChildObject in = myObject.getObjFromVector(0);
```

a copy is made of object referred to by the return value of `getObjFromVector()` as `in` is of type `ChildObject`, not `ChildObject&`.

The second example passes the reference returned directly to the function so no object slicing occurs.

Comment: Ha, i had tried that as well must have had something else wrong. Thanks that did the trick.